GDAL Installation Issues on Anaconda (gdalinfo.exe Entry Point Not Found Error)
I’m struggling to get GDAL working in my Anaconda environment on Windows. Despite multiple attempts, gdalinfo --version consistently returns an entry point error, preventing GDAL from functioning. I'm trying to use GDAL to convert .img files to CSV format with georeferenced data (latitude and longitude).

Environment Details:
Python 3.12.3, GDAL 3.6.2 (installed via conda-forge)
conda install -c conda-forge gdal=3.6.2 python=3.12
conda install -n base --override-channels -c conda-forge mamba 'python_abi=\*=*cp*'

I’ve also verified paths (GDAL_DATA and DLLs in Library/bin), yet the error persists. Has anyone encountered this issue with GDAL in Anaconda or Windows? Any guidance is appreciated.

When using conda it is in general a good idea to avoid mixing packages from different channels.
Anaconda and miniconda use defaults as default channel, so when you use conda install -c conda-forge gdal only gdal will be installed from the conda-forge channel and most other dependencies will be installed from defaults, possibly leading to incompatibilities and problems loading dlls like the one you see.
So, when you want to install something explicitly from the conda-forge channel, it is a good idea to create a new environment and configure it so the highest priority is given to conda forge for everything being installed in this environment, like this:
conda create -n gdal_cf
conda activate gdal_cf
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install gdal

This typically avoids this kind of issues.
Reference: here.
